# How can I shorten a singleton call?

Tags: c++

I have a singleton class that basically deals with logs. Every place at which I call it in the code, I have to type:

```
LogClass::GetInstance()->WriteToLog("text");
```

How can I shorten this call so that I can just type `WriteToLog("text")` and it will call the function on the singleton object?

Comment: Don't use Singletons?

Comment: @DeadMG Been through this before.  Some people don't like singletons, but no one was able to give a valid reason why not.

Comment: Is there anything that stops you doing the obvious thing of writing a free function called `WriteToLog` that simply wraps the `GetInstance()` / `WriteToLog()` functionality?

Comment: @James: I think the general idea is one of principle, that you're not allowing yourself multiple, encapsulated objects of a single given type, but you _are_ using objects, and that therefore you might be using objects for no reason (and thus falling into the trap of "always use an object", which is a myth). Of course, in practice, this falls down pretty quickly as the control you get over instantiation is oft-invaluable.

Comment: @Tomalak I quite agree that the general idea is one of principle.  An arbitrary principle, adopted by a small group of people, who seem to be trying to impose it on others as a religion.  (To be fair, there was one concrete objection presented: that singleton's make unit testing more difficult.  This hasn't been my experience: I've worked on a number of projects which used singletons and extensive unit tests.  But I can imagine test harnesses that were less flexibly, and caused it to be a problem.)

Comment: @James: I don't like singletons because (a) they involve a globally-accessible object, and I like structured designs; (b) they embed the mechanics of object management into the class itself, and I like the flexibility of separating object management from implementation; (c) in C++, they are difficult to implement safely.

Comment: I've had this argument with people too, who basically say it's a problem for unit testing, which doesn't seem like a knock-down argument to me. Although ease-of-unit-testing is one possible design objective, it's certainly not the only one, or even the most important.

Comment: The issue with singletons is that they allow objects or functions to take a silent dependency. Consider the fact that after you construct your object and pass parameters to your function you still haven't provided everything required for your function to perform! IMHO this isn't a problem as long as the singleton's instantiation is self contained i.e. occurs entirely within the GetInstance static function.

Comment: @Mike and Jake Singletons can obviously be abused.  They **are** a form of global variables, and global variables do have their drawbacks.  There are, however, cases where they are justified.  And @Mike: what's the problem in implementing them safely?  (Obviously, in a multithreaded environment, you have to acquire a lock before testing whether the singleton has been instantiated.  But that's no more difficult to handle than any other shared object.)

Comment: @James: the same safety issues you get with any static objects: ensuring they aren't accessed by other static objects before construction or after deletion; ensuring construction and destruction are thread-safe; in a real-time system, ensuring it's constructed before it's needed by critical code, and that you DON'T need to acquire a lock each time it's accessed. All solvable of course, but in my view it's much easier to avoid all these issues completely by not using static objects (dressed up as singletons, or otherwise) unless there's a very good reason to.

Comment: @Mike If you're arguing against static objects in general, that's a different argument.  I can understand some of the reasons for avoiding the, particularly is certain environments.  (On the other hand, I've also worked in environments where dynamic allocation was forbidden.  It all depends on context.)  In a typical desktop environments, singletons and other static objects solve a few problems (not very many) at lower cost than the alternatives.

Comment: @James: An argument against static objects in general also applies to any specific variety of static object. To clarify, my points are: (a) global objects (including singletons) break the structure of a  design through invisible dependencies; (b) singletons couple a class with its lifetime management logic, forcing a particular usage pattern; (c) static objects (including singletons) are difficult to manage safely, for reasons including the ones I just mentioned.

Comment: @Mike (a) Applies to global objects---not all singletons are global, and there are typically one or two things in an application which should be global. (b) And?  The actual lifetime of an object is often part of its contract.  And an object should be responsible for maintaining its contract.  (c) Objects shared between threads may be difficult to manage safely---a singleton is no more difficult than any other object.

Comment: Singeltons are fine if used correctly. Its just that simple examples do not portray the complexities of singelton usage. To use it well (so that you are not tied down) it should be used in conjunction with other constructor patterns (eg potentialy a factory so that different actual objects can be used in different situations. The factory can the build a test singleton for testing and Windows singleton for windows etc...) Its just that a singelton can not be used (it can but it makes life harder in the long run) as a single design pattern it needs to be used in conjunction with other patterns.

Comment: @James: (a) If your singletons aren't global, then they're not as bad as if they were; but the one in this question is global. And even if you do think you need a global object or two, why should they also be singletons? (b) Some people think that separation of concerns if a good design principle. I can't think of a good reason for an object to care how its users choose to manage its lifetime, let alone enforce a particular, rather restrictive, pattern. (c) I mentioned several issues with static objects; thread-safe lifetime management is just one of them.

Comment: @James: my main problem with singletons is that they combine three qualities (global accessibility, static storage duration, and coupling of object lifetime with functionality) which, in my opinion, should each be avoided unless there's a compelling reason for it. Too many people, perceiving a need for one of these qualities, reach for the singleton and introduce more undesirable qualities. If you don't think these qualities are particularly bad, then I don't think I'll be able to explain why I think singletons should be avoided in all but the most bizarre circumstances.

Comment: @Mike (a) Because the design says that there should only be one of them, (b) A key feature of OO is encapsulation---why should some other object be concerned with my lifetime.

Comment: @Mike Singleton and global accessibility are largely orthogonal.  And a singleton doesn't have static storage duration---that's often a motivation for using it.  And the functionality and lifetime are coupled: if the object doesn't exist, it can't function:-).  But seriously, many objects control there own lifetime, directly or indirectly, as part of their functionality.  It's a basic principle of encapsulation: why should something exterior be involved.

Comment: @James: (a) If a system design calls for one object, then only create one in that system. By implementing a requirement of one particular system as a restriction on the use of a class, you've made that class unusable in systems with other requirements. (b) To me, "encapsulation" means separating an object's implementation details from its public interface, and says nothing about restricting how the object can be managed. Other objects should control its lifetime, because they are responsible for combining objects to build the system (unless the system is just a pile of global objects).

Comment: @James: "Many objects control there own lifetime" - not in my code, they don't. Each object has a well-defined functional responsibility, and other objects are responsible for combining as many of them as necessary to make whatever system I might be building.

Comment: @Mike (a) Quite.  An object designed to do one job isn't necessarily appropriate to do another.  In the end, I think it is the argument for/against static type checking.  A tradeoff between flexibility and robustness.  At one extreme: Smalltalk, and at the other (probably) Ada 95.  Globally, I think C++ is closer to Ada 95 that it is to Smalltalk, and robustness has been very important in the things I've worked on.  (b) Encapsulation means (not only) that an object assumes the responsibility for its contract.  And typically, lifetime is part of that contract.

Comment: @Mike.  In most of my work, objects react to external events.  The log off request from a client is treated by the connection object, for example; the connection processes requests from the client, and when it finishes processing the log off request, it deletes itself.  This model is very frequent in certain types of applications (where most `delete` are `delete this`).

Comment: @James: Very well, if you have a design approach that blends an objects's functionality with its lifetime management, then one of my three specific objections to the singleton "pattern" doesn't apply. It's still a valid objection in the context of other design approaches, and my other objections (that globals should generally be avoided, and that making an object available at all times is hard to do correctly) still stand even if you do think it's appropriate to place restrictions on how an object can be incorporated into a larger system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use a reference and an operator() overload.

In LogClass.h file

```
class LogClass
{
    public:

        static LogClass& GetInstance()
        {
            static LogClass singleton;
            return singleton;
        }

        void operator()( std::string msg );

        //...
};


extern LogClass& myDebug;
```

In LogClass.cpp file

```
LogClass& myDebug = LogClass::GetInstance();

void LogClass::operator()( std::string msg )
{
    // my stuff to to with the msg...
}

//...
```

Then, I can use it this way (in any file LogClass.h is included):

```
myDebug("text");
```

Indeed, you must keep in mind that **it's a global variable**...
but on another side the **GetInstance method is called once**.

---

Next I do like to add an easy switch to deactivate all debugMsg at once...

so I add the following:

```
#if DEBUG_MODE
    #define MY_DEBUG( msg ) myDebug( msg )
#else
    #define MY_DEBUG( msg ) // will replace the myDebug calls by nothing.
#endif
```

Thus, I can use:

```
MY_DEBUG("text");  // instead of myDebug("text");
```

So I can easily turn off all the debug messages at once.

Comment: great idea i liked it but why not to use the MACRO like Tomalak Geret'kal suggested?

Comment: In fact there is two reasons: First it was a design choice to make it usable just like std::cout or std::cerr (My printDebug class inherit std::ostream so it can be used as std::cout with manipulators etc... and I pass the channels/verbosity in the parenthesis). This way I can do `myDebug(V_CRITICAL, {1,2,3}) << "val:" << myVal << std::endl;` to send a critical debug message on channels 1,2 and 3. (But this can be done with the macro too...)

Comment: Next, the second reason is for optimization purpose; as I use it for very intensive debug output (thousands of debug messages per seconds) I decided to call the GetInstance method once instead of calling it each time I want to push a new message.

Comment: To finish, I think the MACRO like Tomalak Geret'kal suggested is better than my solution. But I had to suggest the idea (ideas give ideas) and this is a solution if we want to avoid the recursive GetInstance call.

Answer (score 9):

Use a forwarding function

```
inline void WriteToLog(...string...)
{ LogClass::GetInstance()->WriteToLog(.....string......); }
```

Comment: and put in where ? in the LogClass ? or in some kind of global include h file ?

Comment: Outside the class, or somewhere else where it is needed.

Comment: Put the above code in the C++ file where you implement LogClass, and put a prototype to that function at the bottom of the header file where you declare LogClass.

Comment: why i need prototype in the bottom? can you give example?

Comment: @user63898 - You don't need a separate prototype if you add the inline function there. Inline functions are much preferred over macros though. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Add a static function to LogClass:

```
class LogClass {

    static void Write( const std::string & s ) {
         GetInstannce()->WriteToLog( s );
     }
};
```

then:

```
LogClass::Write( "foobar" );
```

Comment: can i somehow to dismiss the LogClass? and only be able to write 
Write() in each place?

Comment: @user Do what the others suggest and write  a free function. But I like the static option better - it's clearer what is going on.

Answer (score 5):

```
#define LOG(str) LogClass::GetInstance()->WriteToLog(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can a pointer to temporarily store an alias of the class locally in your function:
(Assuming "GetInstance returns a pointer to the singleton)

```
 void foo()
 {
    Singleton* logger = LogClass::GetInstance();
    logger->WriteToLog(...string...);
    logger->WriteToLog(...string...);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I find it bad practice to expose the "Singleton".

I used to have `static` functions over a `static` state:

```
class Logger {
public:
  static void Write(std::string const& s);
private:
  static std::ifstream _file;
};
```

However, I much prefer using Monoids now. They are just Singletons in disguise, of course, but it's much easier to migrate away from singleton-ness afterwards.

```
class Logger {
public:
  void Write(std::string const& s);
private:
  static std::ifstream _file;
};
```

You still have to handle all the Singletons issues, but you can migrate away from it with more ease.